# Blackberry border color in editfield when focused

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I want to place solid border and border color to the `EditField` in blackberry when it is focused.Hers is my screenshot http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=yst9bgev9crqjny&thumb=4.Please help

Answer (score 1):

Override [onFocus](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#onFocus%28int%29) and [onUnfocus](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#onUnfocus%28%29) methods in your field class.

And draw colored rectangle around input field area.